# Jmeter - query, store in variable. Now use that variable in post-processing

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Looking to utilize jmeter for some automated testing but facing a problem. preliminary to my tests I want to run a query on my DB and then store the result in a text file.

I thought I'd do it via a JDBC request as such:

[image: (blurred out some stuff, but you get the idea)]

Then immediately after I want to do some post-processing that writes the result to our file:

[image]

I've tried, too, putting the paramater passed to vars.get in quotation marks, but I get no such luck. Jmeter does write a file, but that file is empty, and if I run the query independently, it does return results.

Does anybody know how to get this desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into *jmeter.log* file you should see a Beanshell Related error.

This is due to "Result Variable Name" being an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), not String, hence

1. You need to use [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) method instead of `vars.get()`;
2. Ensure you quote the variable name
3. Remove the ";" at end of SQL Query
4. You need to iterate the [ArrayList](http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/) somehow or [serialize](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/) it to file.
5. If result set is large it's better to consider doing it via [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using "groovy" as a language as Beanshell has some performance limitations. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for benchmarking results and instructions on how to setup groovy scripting engine support.
6. To write the output to a file , see :

   [Append data into a file using Apache Commons I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966333/append-data-into-a-file-using-apache-commons-i-o)

If you decide to use Groovy it will be even easier :

- http://grails.asia/groovy-file-examples